# Как получить последнее число !=0 и все что после в regex?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пример вывода

910 → 10

9101 → 1

1000 → 1000

1012200 → 200

вариант
`([^0])(?!.*\1)` почему то не работает

Comment: регулярки не всесильны

Comment: `[1-9]0*$` — https://regex101.com/r/aUJLtw/1

Comment: @Jean-Claude Не хотите оформить свой комментарий как ответ ?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude а как?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const test_data = ['910', '9101', '1000', '1012200', '910910', '91019101', '10001000', '10122001012200', '0', '000', '001', '0010'];

const regex = /[1-9]0*$/;

for (t in test_data) {
  let m = test_data[t].match(regex);
  if (m !== null) {
    console.log(test_data[t], '---', m[0]);
  } else {
    console.log(test_data[t], '---', null);
  }
}
```